# Removing a drop down list option based on previous cell selection

Tags: excel, vba

[Overview of worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwqLJ.jpg) I have created a dependent drop down list in a cell that changes according to a data input in another. I want to be able to automatically remove a listed option in a third cell (the target setting cell) if a previously corresponding evaluation option has been selected. The idea here is that if an ‘objective’ within the evaluation [Evaluation objectives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEbuk.jpg) of the student work has been identified then the class teacher would not be able to accidentally also select the same ‘objective’ target [Target objectives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etzkf.jpg) and avoid contradicting the evaluation. My columns run their If statements [If statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O2X9.jpg) correctly so that multiple selections can be made but I want the Target drop down list to deplete/remove (not display) any choice that has already been made in the Evaluation.

Threshold - Evaluation - Target

I’m really perplexed with this. My data look up (target sheets) uses cell references in a corresponding sheet which holds both evaluation and targets placed sequentially [Paired objectives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znsAe.jpg) in pairs. Therefore Evaluation A1 matches to Target B1 and so on. This is text not numerical. I considered numbering each within their cell so that when selected the associated number would also be displayed. If a Threshold was Developing then D1 would be assigned for first Evaluation objective with corresponding D1 for Target. Thereby if there is a statement attached to the Target cell that queries the existence of D1 within the Evaluation cell then remove D1 from the Target drop down list so that it is not presented as an option for selection.

Here's the vba code [Multiple selection VBA coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpjwM.jpg) that allows multiple selections from the drop downs.

Seems logical but cumbersome. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: It would really help your question to explain exactly *how* your current setup works, and ideally show one or two screenshots (source data, and data entry) or some sample data to help illustrate the problem. You mention "drop down list" but don't mention what type of list you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Tim - I've only just registered so I cannot upload images directly - I have placed the links to the content if you wouldn't mind taking a look over it.
Much appreciated.  For clarification - I have had to hide the data sensitive student name column in the screenshots.  Thanks.

Comment: I’ve been playing around with it and think I’ve come up with my own solution namely to assume all Targets have not been met and present them automatically in the Target drop down for them only to be removed automatically by formula in Evaluation drop down if they match the validation. This way teachers won’t need to select Targets, (one less task to perform - win!) they will automatically be generated from the unselected Evaluation criteria.  Thanks for giving me a space to think out loud.

Comment: Yep. Works a treat.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out.